# Passwords and usernames always fail to authenticate within an SSH session

Tags: ssh

I don't know if it's bad luck or what, but every time I try to enter usernames and passwords for other services (BitBucket, Github, sensitive data that doesn't show on the terminal) after signing into an SSH session (school computer running SunOS), they always fail to authenticate.

I can't clone my private assignment repos on BitBucket. I can't change my password with `passwd`. It's driving me insane.

Those things usually work on my first or second try on my Linux system on both my laptop and desktop, just not inside an SSH session (from either Linux or PUTTY), and I've tried at least a dozen times by now, on different days too.

Sample usage transcript:

SSH into school:

```
[me@home.com ~]$ ssh me@school.edu
Password:
[me@school.edu ~]$ passwd
passwd: Changing password for me
Enter existing login password:
passwd: Sorry, wrong passwd
Permission denied
[me@school.edu ~]$ passwd me
Enter existing login password:
passwd: Sorry, wrong passwd
Permission denied
[me@school.edu ~]$ git clone https://bitbucket.org/me/a1
Cloning into a1...
error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed while accessing https://bitbucket.org/me/a1/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
[me@school.edu ~]$ git config --global http.sslVerify false
[me@school.edu ~]$ git clone https://bitbucket.org/me/a1
Cloning into a1...
Username:
Password:
fatal: Authentication failed
```

Cloning at home:

```
[me@home.com ~]$
[me@home.com ~]$ git clone https://bitbucket.org/me/a1
Cloning into 'a1'...
Username for https://bitbucket.org: me
Password for :https://me@bitbucket.org:
remote: Counting objects: ...
remote: Compressing objects...
remote: Total ...
Unpacking...
[me@home.com ~]$
```

Output of `locale`:

```
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: So you can sign into these without trouble if you don't SSH to school?  The question may be clearer if you define fake hostnames for your school server, Linux system, laptop, and desktop, and list your steps in chronological order.

Comment: @axus Yeah, it seems that every time sensitive information (doesn't echo to screen) has to be entered fails

Comment: Try the second answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178401/how-can-i-debug-git-git-shell-related-problems for debugging, and maybe test your hidden input with "read -s var; echo $var" to make sure you're not going crazy :)  Also, is your $SHELL set to bash on the SunOS system?

Comment: Could you copy/paste the output when you run the "locale" command ?

Comment: @Algeriassic done. They're mostly C

Comment: @Alex, what do you mean mostly C ?
Do you see (LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8") ?

Comment: @Algeriassic They're literally all along the lines of `LC_CTYPE="C"`, the default POSIX locale: C locale. None of them are UTF of any kind. It was added it to the bottom of my post

Comment: @Alex Did you check the keyboard layout ?
Try this `more /etc/default/keyboard | grep XKBLAYOUT` to see what layout you are using.